# jquery mobile listview change link arrow by custom image icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I using jqm listview, I triying to change a link arrow by personal image icon, is there way to change it, the image below, show that I want.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h2></h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create css for each custom icon

```
.ui-icon-myIcon1:after {
    background-image: url("../_assets/img/glyphish-icons/21-skull.png");
    background-position: 3px 3px;
    background-size: 70%;
}
```

Then use data-icon to reference your custom icon name:

```
<li data-icon="myIcon1" id="skull"><a href="#">custom-icon</a></li>
```

See the icons:standard section of the official listview demo: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/